# What is the geometric meaning of inner product of $\nabla f$ and $\nabla f_x$?

Tags: differential-geometry, computer-science, image-processing

I am working on $3D$ imaging and I encoded one method through its Matlab code. The program used the following expression for a function $f:\Bbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ modelizing the $3D$ image,
$$ \nabla f.(\nabla f.\nabla f_x, \nabla f. \nabla f_y, \nabla f.\nabla f_z )$$
where $f_x$ denotes the $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and so on. What does that mean geometrically ? On the other hand, it is well known that the inner product of two vectors is connected with the angle between them. But I am confused about the above expression. So, I want to ask "Is there any book or article to describe the above expression? " or " What does that mean in terms of geometrical concepts ?".

Comment: That's pretty peculiar language; I'd write to the authors and say something like "I don't understand your notation. Suppose that $f(x, y, z) = x^2 - y^2z$, Can you tell me what this expression you wrote would denote in that case?"

Comment: Perhaps it is the hessian contracted with the gradient from both sides?

Comment: $cos^{-1}(\langle a, b\rangle (\langle a, a\rangle)^{-1/2}(\langle b, b\rangle)^{-1/2})$ is the angle between a and b (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Norms_on_inner_product_spaces).

Comment: Dear @JohnHughes

If $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2 z$ then 
$$\nabla f =(2x,-2yz,-y^2)~~(gradient f)$$
and for $f_x, f_y, f_z$ one has
$$f_x=2x, f_y=-2yz, -y^2$$
then 
$$\nabla f_x=(2,0,0), \nabla f_y=(0,-2z,-2y), \nabla f_z=(0,-2y,0)$$
Further:
$$\nabla f . \nabla f_x =(2x,-2yz,-y^2)(2,0,0)^T =4x$$
$$\nabla f. \nabla f_y =(2x,-2yz,-y^2)(0,-2z,-2y)^T=4yz^2+2y^3$$
$$\nabla f. \nabla f_z=(2x,-2yz,-y^2)(0,-2y,0)^T=4y^2z$$
So
$$(\nabla f.\nabla f_x, \nabla f. \nabla f_y, \nabla f.\nabla f_z )=(4x, 4yz^2+2y^3, 4y^2z)$$
Finally the inner product of this vector with $\nabla f$ should be computed.

Comment: I grant that this is one interpretation. It's completely inconsistent with @Anthony's answer, however, which involves second derivatives. That suggests at the very least that the notation is ambiguous, and a note to the authors might help disambiguate.

Comment: @JohnHughes: but it's the same - they have differentiated once to get $f_x$, etc, and then again to get $\nabla f_x$. I don't think it's ambiguous at all so long as the subscript derivative notation is understood.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this expression as 
$$ \nabla^2 f(\nabla f, \nabla f) = \nabla f^T \ \nabla^2 f \ \nabla f.$$

Here $\nabla^2 f$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$; i.e. $(\nabla^2 f)_{ij} = \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$.

One way to interpret this is as the second derivative of $f$ in the direction $\nabla f$: we have

$$\nabla^2 f(\nabla f, \nabla f)|_\vec{x} = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\Big|_{t=0} f(\vec x + t \nabla f).$$

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Through to your notation I think that if I set 
$$\nabla f^T \nabla^2 f \nabla f =0$$
then I can find the maximum, minimum and inflection points which are very important points in image processing. Finally, I will be very thankful if you have another idea about the concept of that.

Comment: @yaser setting that equal to zero only implies that the restriction of f to the line in the direction $\nabla u$ has an inflection point, nothing more. If you're looking to identify and classify critical points you need to study $\nabla u$ and $\nabla^2 u$ separately.